# why we use " $ " in MongoDb aggregations?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
$lookup : {
  from: "categories",
  localField: "_id",
  foreignField: "userId",
  as: "categories_details"
}
```

Why we used "$" as a prefix of lookup here?

Comment: Because it's a special key, sort of like a command for mongo.

Answer (score 0):

It is the syntax of MongoDB. It is not used only in Aggregation framework, but in basic query syntax too.

###### Places where **$** is used:

1. Operators have the prefix of **$** in theirs names - Ex: `$eq`, `$in`, `$and`...
2. Stages in Aggregation framework have prefix of **$** in theirs names - Ex: `$set`, `$group`, `$project`...
3. In Aggregation pipeline, when you want to access the value of some field of the current document, you should use the prefix of **$** with the name of that field

Answer (score 0):

$ sign in MongoDB usually refers to many things, depends where and how to use it:

1. **"$" is reserved for operators:** It could be used with some operators like $gte, $in, $eq, or $lookup, this way we're telling mongo to treat next expression according to that operator prefixed with $ sign.
2. **"$field-name":** If $ sign was used inside a string with a field name, the $ in this case is referred to the root document field, for example:

   {
   "$sum": {
   "$map": {
   "input": "$data",
   "as": "currentData",
   "in": { "$size": "$$currentData.d" }
   }
   }
   }

Here '$data' is the document array field.

3. **"$$variable":** Sometimes $ sign can be used to refer to variables, so according to previous code, "$$currentData" is the variable taken in the as expression of $map aggregation.
4. **$ (update):** The positional $ operator identifies an element in an array to update without explicitly specifying the position of the element in the array. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_)
5. **$ (projection):** The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  to return the first element that matches the query condition on the array. You can read more about this [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)